# Laravel Null Session

Tags: php, laravel, session, null, captcha

Creating a simple captcha with gd library, setting session to be used later on form, but when I want to get the value, it's NULL.

I have put it into web middleware group in routes which has the `sessionstart` in it.

Inside my captcha controller:

```
session(["captcha"=>$rand]);
```

Inside my other methods in other controller:

```
$captcha = session("captcha");

dd($captcha); // returns null
```

Comment: try to print value of $rand before passing it to the session see if it has a valid value

Comment: also checkout this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Check if the value `$rand` is being set. Check if you've set the correct session driver and if it's working. Try to set and fetch from session to version that the data is being set.

Comment: @SapneshNaik the $rand variable has value, because of that the image of captcha working correctly, so it has value.

Comment: @Sandeesh It's set, because of that I have captcha image. Its driver is set to file, should it be something else?

Comment: File session driver is default and works fine. Can you share your session setting controller logic? Also the controller method where you want to fetch the session value should also use the `web` middleware group.

Comment: I got the answer, because refreshing captcha with ajax didn't work, I decided to put exit in last line, now when I deleted that it worked :) thank you all